# How to handle multiple states of objects efficiently

Tags: java

I have a function like this

```
public void function(operand left, operand right){}
```

The operand is an interface and different classes can inherit from it, the interface has a method called

```
int getIdentity()
```

It returns an int, right now there are three classes that inherit it real, imaginary and complex. And they return the following ints from the `getIdentity()` method REAL = 1, IMAG = 2, COMPLEX = 3.

In the method `function` I handle it like this :

```
switch(left.getIdentity()){
    case REAL -> {
        switch(right.getIdentity()){
            case REAL -> {
                //unique case handle
            }
            case IMAG -> {
                //unique case handle
            }
            case COMPLEX -> {
                //unique case handle
            }
        }
    }
    case IMAG -> {
        switch(right.getIdentity()){
            case REAL -> {
                //unique case handle
            }
            case IMAG -> {
                //unique case handle
            }
            case COMPLEX -> {
                //unique case handle
            }
        }
    }
    case COMPLEX -> {
        switch(right.getIdentity()){
            case REAL -> {
                //unique case handle
            }
            case IMAG -> {
                //unique case handle
            }
            case COMPLEX -> {
                //unique case handle
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As its clear, it's very tiresome to check for all possible unique combinations, as more classes will inherit from this interface, testing the unique combinations will become even more tiresome. So I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to handle this type of situations.

Comment: What is that function meant to do?

Comment: Disclaimer: This is my view only :: From the above it seems to me that the above could be better done with method overloading. If the 'function' has three variant which handles input of different types, the design would be cleaner. Inheritance is useful to process parts of the class hierarchy which can be commonly handled.